# Layout during navigation takes too long

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, .net-4.5

I have a application whitch consists of some pages.
On most pages DataGrid controll exists. Each DataGrid has `EnableColumnVirtualization` and `EnableRowVirtualization` set to `True`.
To navigate through pages I use `NavigationManager` instance taken from `Frame`.
Layout of a DataGrid takes about 300 ms. And when switching pages in such way a lag exists. 
Can some one give me a peace of advice how can I improve perfomance?

Comment: Just have a page cache that will maintain a couple of pages.

Comment: I have an MVVM arch. ViewModels were resoved to view using DataTemplates